# Shopify output content after title

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I learning how to build app's for Shopify. I need to output some data after product title. I can do that with script_tags.json like this:

index.php:

```
$array = array(
    'script_tag' => array(
        'event' => 'onload', 
        'src' => 'https://mywebsite.com/shopify/scripts/shopify.js'
    )
);
    
$scriptTag = shopify_call($token, $shop, "/admin/api/2019-07/script_tags.json", $array, 'POST');
$scriptTag = json_decode($scriptTag['response'], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

shopify.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('h1').after('<div class="iconbar">My data</div>');
});
```

It's OK, but what if some template doesn't have h1 tag for title?
Is it possible to using {{ product.title }} from product-template.liquid as selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access liquid logic from Javascript.

The generation of the liquid code is done before the Javascript starts executing.

There is no way to achieve what you are looking without setting a static hook of some sort (a.k.a tag or class)

If you are coding this for a specific client and theme inform the client that he must use a specific tag or class.

If you are coding this for multiply stores add an option in the back-end to allow for the client to select the tag or class he can target with the app and request that information from your JS in order to know what to target dynamically for each separate store.

Comment: I understood correctly that there is no other possibility to modify frontend via APP's? Only with JavaScript DOM element selection?

Comment: @user3514052 You can use Assets API as well, but that will be а destructive change (a.k.a. your code will be present when the client deletes your app). That way you will have access to the liquid code, but I really hate APPs that modify theme files, so I don't recommend it.